# How to find limit of this function

Tags: limits

> If $f(x) f(1/x) = f(x) + f(1/x)$ and $f(2) > 1$, then $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ is:

[image: Original image]

My professor told me to use the squeeze theorem whenever we are to find the limit of an unknown function. I don't think that it will be applicable here as no desire information is given here. Then how to find a limit in this question?

Comment: Can you turn your picture please, it is hard to read.

Comment: My picture is in landscape mode but after uploading it automatically changes to portrait mode

Comment: Can we just define $f(x)=2$?

Comment: Is it given that $f(x)$ a polynomial? If it's I am getting 2.

Comment: @BorKari No, how do you know that the limit is equal to that of $f(x)=2$ for all functions with the property above

Comment: why not assuming that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x)$ defined, and then we can also write $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x)f(1/x)= f(1)f(1)=f(1)+f(1) $$
this can be written as $$f(1)^2 -2f(1) = 0 \rightarrow f(1)(f(1)-2)=0$$ which leads into 2 options, then eliminate $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (otherwise just set $f(x)=2$ for $x\leq 0$). If $f$ is not continuous, it may happen that the limit does not exist. To see why this is true, take $$f(x)=\begin{cases}c, &\text{ if }x>1\\ \frac{c}{c-1}, &\text{ if }x<1\\0,&\text{ if } x=1\end{cases}$$ with $c>1$.

If we suppose that $f$ is indeed continuous, it is not hard to see that there is no positive $x$, such that $f(x)=1$. This, combined with the fact that $f(2)>1$, gives $f(x)>1$ for all positive $x$. This gives $f(1)=2$ and so $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)=f(1)=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(f(x)-1)(f(1/x)-1)=1$. So if we guess $f(x)=x^n+1$ then $((x^n+1)-1)((\frac{1}{x^n}+1)-1)$ which equals 1 so our guess was correct.
Therefore, $f(2)=2^n+1>1$ which is true for all $n$. So the limit is simply equal to 2.

Comment: I understand you made a good guess for the function, but that doesn't mean that $2$ is the limit for all possible functions with the given property. It's possible the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: There's no need to 'guess', it can be proved easily. But the restriction is $f(x)$ must be a polynomial.

Comment: My answer is definitely not a rigorous one. Perhaps it's more qualified as a comment.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to discourage Akshat by giving him a  down vote. His solution is partly correct. (+1) from me